Handling Stripe `charge.refunded` webhook call - how to link my own order
I have a very simple checkout session Stripe flow for taking payments and
also already handling checkout.session.completed webhook calls in my API.
When I create a checkout session with stripe.checkout.session.create(),
I send my order number as client_reference_id and some additional info as metadata.
I would like to use this client_reference_id or a similar value in
charge.refunded event but not sure how I could get the related
checkout session object?
Maybe there is a better Stripe way of doing this?
I would like to avoid storing chargeID in my database/app,
but maybe that's the recommended way?
Thanks

The metadata that you place on a Checkout Session is not automatically copied to related objects created by that session. 0
You can use payment_intent_data.metadata1 when creating your Checkout Session to provide metadata that will be placed on the Payment Intent created by the Checkout Session. Stripe does automatically do a one-time copy of a Payment Intent's metadata to the underlying Charge object when that's created. That would allow you to provide your metadata while creating the Checkout Session, but see it on Payment Intent and Charge related Events.
A couple important notes on this approach:

The copy of metadata from the Payment Intent to the Charge is a one-time copy. If you need to update the metadata on those objects, you will need to explicitly update it on each object.
payment_intent_data.metadata is not visible on the Checkout Session once it's been created. If you need to see that metadata in Checkout Session related Events then you'll also want to continue providing it as metadata on the Checkout Session itself.

